# Leaflet Legend for Custom Markers in R

Tags: r, leaflet, legend

I have an R Shiny app that uses Leaflet to create an interactive map.  On this map, a categorical variable is used to designate different kinds of points and is visualized using custom markers (different icons, depending on the factor level).

What I would like to do is add a legend to the plot, but have the legend show the various marker icons instead of solid colours.  The [legends tutorial](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html) does not cover this.

I have come across another [SO answer that seems to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701211/custom-legend-image-as-legend-in-leaflet-map) - but it was done in JavaScript and I'm not sure how to translate it/if it can be translated to work in R. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

A basic reproducible example:

```
library(leaflet)

# Sample Data
data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

# Choose Icon:
leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = ifelse(quakes$mag < 4.6,
                   "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
                   "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

# Produce Map:
leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons)
```

Comment: If it works, the simplest way is probably just to source the JavaScript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While the use of icons is [not currently implemented](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/191) in addLegend(), Yihui suggested the use of addControl(), using raw html - which works perfectly!

```
library(leaflet)

# Sample Data
data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

# Choose Icon:
leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = ifelse(quakes$mag < 4.6,
                   "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
                   "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png'>green<br/>
<img src='http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png'>red"

# Produce Map:
leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons) %>%
  addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft")
```

#### Links

- Green: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png
- Red: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png
- Orange: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-orange.png

Which produces:

[image: Leaflet Map with Categorical Legend]

Comment: Tried this and it works but the icons in the legend are really large. Is there a way to resize them in the html_legend code or addControl()?

Comment: Yes, the icon size is defined in the icons() call, in the above they are set to 38px wide and 95px tall.

Answer (score 9):

Responding to the comment above: you can change the size of the icons in the legend, regardless of the initial size you define. All you have to do is add

`style='width:(desired_width)px;height:(desired_height)px';`
 to the HTML portion.

Specifically, your code would like:

```
library(leaflet)

# Sample Data
data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

# Choose Icon:
leafIcons <- icons(
iconUrl = ifelse(quakes$mag < 4.6,
               "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
               "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png'
style='width:10px;height:10px;'>green<br/> 

<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png'  
style='width:10px;height:10px;'>red"

# Produce Map:
leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons) %>%
addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go so far as the raw HTML implementation of `addControl`.  You can still use `addLegend`.

The key is knowing how it's implemented under the hood.  When you specify a color in `addLegend`, it becomes the value for the `background` parameter in the CSS applied to the legend.  So, instead of declaring a color, just declare a url to the image you want in the legend:

```
leafletProxy() %>% 
addLegend( 
   'bottomleft' , 
   colors=c(
      "url('http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png')",
      "url('http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png')"
   ),
   labels=c('Green','Red') 
)
```