# leaflet legend for Custom Awesome Marker in R?

Tags: r, geolocation, leaflet, visualization, geospatial

I need to add some custom marker legends to my leaflet map. So far, the closest solution I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862467/leaflet-legend-for-custom-markers-in-r). According to the solution in the link, I need to use the  `addControl()` function.

First I have to link the custom images in html format. See below:

```
html_legend <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png'
style='width:10px;height:10px;'>green<br/> 

<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png'  
style='width:10px;height:10px;'>red"
```

I then use the `html_legend` as an argument to the `addControl()` function:

```
addMarkers(...)%>%
addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft")
```

---

How can I get the same outcome when using Awesome Icons?

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064921/leaflet-legend-for-addawesomemarkers-function-with-icons) may help. I tried it out and it works.