# R leaflet - Show/Hide addControl() element with group layers

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, leaflet

I have a leaflet map which uses a custom legend using HTML and added using the `addControl` function (following: [Leaflet Legend for Custom Markers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862467/leaflet-legend-for-custom-markers-in-r)).

However, I only want the legend to show when one group is shown, I have tried using the argument `group = "group name"`which doesn't work with the `addControl` function. I've also tried using `layerId` arguments but without success.

Any ideas?

Reproducible example:

```
library(leaflet)
# Sample Data
data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

# Choose Icon:
leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = ifelse(quakes$mag < 4.6,
               "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
               "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png"
 ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-
green.png'>green<br/>
<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png'>red"

# Produce Map:
leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group A") %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group B") %>%
  addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft") %>%
  addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))
```

Where I would like the `addControl` html_legend element to only be visible when Group A is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, now I think i understand your problem. Below is another example, which shows only the legend and control of the active groups. For that, I created 2 html_legends for group A and for group B.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

html_legend_A <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png'>green<br/>"
html_legend_B <- "<img src='http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png'>red<br/>"

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    map <- leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group A", layerId = "A") %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group B", layerId = "B") %>%
      addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))
    map
  })

  observe({
    map <- leafletProxy("map") %>% clearControls()
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group A")) {
      map <- map %>% 
        addControl(html = html_legend_A, layerId = "A", position = "bottomleft") %>% 
        addLegend(title="Group A", position="bottomright", opacity=1, colors="green",labels = "Group A")}
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group B")) {
      map <- map %>% 
        addControl(html = html_legend_B, layerId = "B", position = "bottomleft") %>% 
        addLegend(title="Group B", position="bottomright", opacity=1,colors="red",labels = "Group B")}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When using the `LayerId` argument, it only shows 1 marker per group. If you want to see all markers, the `LayerId` argument should not be given. I made you another example. I think this should be right now :) I also create 2 icons and I am filtering the quakes data, based on the mag-column inside the renderLeaflet function, as you do in the icon assignment.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

leafIcons_A <- icons(
  iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)
leafIcons_B <- icons(
  iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png",
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend_A <- "<img src='https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png'>green<br/>"
html_legend_B <- "<img src='https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png'>red<br/>"

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    dataA <- quakes[quakes$mag < 4.6,]
    dataB <- quakes[quakes$mag > 4.6,]

    map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(dataA$long, dataA$lat, icon = leafIcons_A, group = "Group A") %>%
      addMarkers(dataB$long, dataB$lat, icon = leafIcons_B, group = "Group B") %>%
      addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))
    map
  })

  observe({
    map <- leafletProxy("map") %>% clearControls()
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group A")) {
      map <- map %>%
        addControl(html = html_legend_A, position = "bottomleft") %>%
        addLegend(title="Group A", position="bottomright", opacity=1, colors="green",labels = "Group A")}
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group B")) {
      map <- map %>%
        addControl(html = html_legend_B, position = "bottomleft") %>%
        addLegend(title="Group B", position="bottomright", opacity=1,colors="red",labels = "Group B")}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was hoping to achieve!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make a Shiny-App out of this? I wrote something similar for a Siny-App, where only the legend of the clicked groups appear.

If its not supposed to be a shiny-app, you could do something like this (you have to assign the leaflet map to a variable (in this case "map"). So you can call it and adapt it afterwards.

```
map <- leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group A") %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group B") %>%
  addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft") %>%
  addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))

groups <- map$x$calls[[5]]$args[[2]]
activeGroup <- map$x$calls[[3]]$args[[5]]

if (any(activeGroup %in% "Group A")) {
  map %>% addLegend(title="Group A", position="bottomright", opacity=1, colors="red",
                           labels = "Group A")}

if (any(activeGroup %in% "Group B")) {
   map %>% addLegend(title="Group B", position="bottomright", opacity=1,colors="green",
                           labels = "Group B")}
```

The groups-variable stores all groups, that are at hand, and activeGroup stores the groups, that are active at the moment.
You can then use it with some if-else statements to only show the legend of the active group.

Although, its not gonna be interactive as a normal R-script. You would have to repeatedly call the activeGroup-call, to check which groups are still active. In Shiny, this interactivity would be given.

Here you have the implementation in a shiny-app:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    map <- leaflet(data = quakes) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group A") %>%
      addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons, group = "Group B") %>%
      addControl(html = html_legend, position = "bottomleft")
      addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))
    map
  })

  observe({
    map <- leafletProxy("map") %>% clearControls()

    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group A")) {
      map <- map %>% addLegend(title="Group A", position="bottomright", opacity=1, colors="red",labels = "Group A")}
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group B")) {
      map <- map %>% addLegend(title="Group B", position="bottomright", opacity=1,colors="green",labels = "Group B")}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SeGa . Eventually I would like to make a Shiny app, yes. Your answer actually just show/hides the legend element of the active group which I believe can be achieved more efficiently using the `group =` argument  with `addLegend()` along with `addLayers()`. My problem is the `group =` argument is not valid with `addControl()`. But your solution should work with `addControl()` so if you change your answer accordingly I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: There is no `addLayers()` in the leaflet package (addLayer() is from the raster package). However, I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. Should only the legend of the clicked/active group appear? Or you want something else?

Comment: Sorry, that should have read `addLayersControl()`. What I want to achieve is to have only the `addControl`  (a custom legend in my example) element show for the active group layer it is associated with (Group A  in the example).