# How to turn off the layer display of addLayersControl first when launching the shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am creating an app with shiny + leaflet.
When I launch the shiny app for the very first time, I try to show all the default values of the layers displayed by addLayersControl.
Is there a way to specify show / hide?

For example, if you have the following code.
(See [R leaflet - Show/Hide addControl() element with group layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373497/r-leaflet-show-hide-addcontrol-element-with-group-layers))

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

leafIcons_A <- icons(
  iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)
leafIcons_B <- icons(
  iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png",
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend_A <- "<img src='https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png'>green<br/>"
html_legend_B <- "<img src='https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png'>red<br/>"

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    dataA <- quakes[quakes$mag < 4.6,]
    dataB <- quakes[quakes$mag > 4.6,]
    
    map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(dataA$long, dataA$lat, icon = leafIcons_A, group = "Group A") %>%
      addMarkers(dataB$long, dataB$lat, icon = leafIcons_B, group = "Group B") %>%
      addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))
    map
  })
  
  observe({
    map <- leafletProxy("map") %>% clearControls()
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group A")) {
      map <- map %>%
        addControl(html = html_legend_A, position = "bottomleft") %>%
        addLegend(title="Group A", position="bottomright", opacity=1, colors="green",labels = "Group A")}
    if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group B")) {
      map <- map %>%
        addControl(html = html_legend_B, position = "bottomleft") %>%
        addLegend(title="Group B", position="bottomright", opacity=1,colors="red",labels = "Group B")}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When executed, "GroupA" and "GroupB" are shown by default. Is it possible to control so that only "GroupA" is shown when shiny is started and "GroupB" is hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to add `%>% hideGroup("Group B")` after `addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"))` as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

data(quakes)
quakes <- quakes[1:10,]

leafIcons_A <- icons(
    iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
    iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
    iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)
leafIcons_B <- icons(
    iconUrl = "https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png",
    iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
    iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94)

html_legend_A <- "<img src='https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png'>green<br/>"
html_legend_B <- "<img src='https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png'>red<br/>"

ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        dataA <- quakes[quakes$mag < 4.6,]
        dataB <- quakes[quakes$mag > 4.6,]
        
        map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
            addMarkers(dataA$long, dataA$lat, icon = leafIcons_A, group = "Group A") %>%
            addMarkers(dataB$long, dataB$lat, icon = leafIcons_B, group = "Group B") %>%
            addLayersControl(position = "topleft", overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B")) %>%
            hideGroup("Group B")
        map
    })
    
    observe({
        map <- leafletProxy("map") %>% clearControls()
        if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group A")) {
            map <- map %>%
                addControl(html = html_legend_A, position = "bottomleft") %>%
                addLegend(title="Group A", position="bottomright", opacity=1, colors="green",labels = "Group A")}
        if (any(input$map_groups %in% "Group B")) {
            map <- map %>%
                addControl(html = html_legend_B, position = "bottomleft") %>%
                addLegend(title="Group B", position="bottomright", opacity=1,colors="red",labels = "Group B")}
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There is such a function. I didn't find out enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, you can also switch the if statements in the last observe to display Group A above Group B which seems to make more sense.