# Conflict when generating addPolylines on the map made by Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Friends, could you help me with the following question: I am having a conflict when inserting the addPolylines function to generate my second leaflet map. In general, Map 1 involves showing all clusters and Map 2 involves a specific cluster. For this specific cluster I inserted a feature to adhere the same colors as the clusters formed on the map1. The first code is doing the above descriptions correctly. However, I also inserted the second code that refers to addPolylines for the second map. But when I insert this second code in the first code, in the part that concerns the generation of map 2, it gives an error: `Warning: Error in eval: object 'm2' not found`. Could you help me solve this problem please?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.4,-23.5), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6,-49.4,-49.2), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,]

  #Table to join df and df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, df1))

  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)

  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$Properties,
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 45, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"

  # Map for all clusters:
  m1<-leaflet(df1) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~df$Latitude, lng = ~df$Longitude, icon=icons, label=~as.character(df$cluster)) %>% 
    addPolylines(lat=~df$Latitude, lng = ~df$Longitude,color="red") %>% 
    addLegend( position = "topright", title="Cluster", colors = ai_colors[1:max(df$cluster)],labels = unique(df$cluster))

  plot1<-m1

  # Map for specific cluster and propertie
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon = 'ios-close',
      iconColor = 'black',
      library = 'ion',
      markerColor =  clust_colors)
    m2<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, icon=icons, label=~cluster) 
    plot2<-m2} else plot2 <- NULL   

  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Plot2" = plot2,
    "Data" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 5, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf1",width = "95%", height = "600")))))

                      ))),
  tabPanel("",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
               selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Map", (leafletOutput("Leaf2",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
           )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })

  output$Leaf1 <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

  output$Leaf2 <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[2]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 

  observeEvent(input$Filter1,{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))
  }) 


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Code to insert addPolyline in the second map

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_spec_clust)){
    df_line <- rbind(df_spec_prop[,c("Latitude","Longitude")],
                     df_spec_clust[i,c("Latitude","Longitude")])
    m2 <- m2 %>%
      addPolylines(data = df_line, 
                   lat=~Latitude, 
                   lng = ~Longitude,
                   color="red")
  }
  plot2<-m2
```

**When I insert this second code into the first code regarding the generation of map 2:**

```
 # Map for specific cluster and propertie
      if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
        clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
        icons <- awesomeIcons(
          icon = 'ios-close',
          iconColor = 'black',
          library = 'ion',
          markerColor =  clust_colors)
        m2<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, icon=icons, label=~cluster) 
        plot2<-m2} else plot2 <- NULL   

for(i in 1:nrow(df_spec_clust)){
        df_line <- rbind(df_spec_prop[,c("Latitude","Longitude")],
                         df_spec_clust[i,c("Latitude","Longitude")])
        m2 <- m2 %>%
          addPolylines(data = df_line, 
                       lat=~Latitude, 
                       lng = ~Longitude,
                       color="red")
      }
      plot2<-m2
```

The following error appears:  Warning: Error in eval: object 'm2' not found.```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert the code within the `if` statement:

```
# Map for specific cluster and propertie
if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
        icon = 'ios-close',
        iconColor = 'black',
        library = 'ion',
        markerColor =  clust_colors)
    m2<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
        addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, icon=icons, label=~cluster) 

    for(i in 1:nrow(df_spec_clust)){
        df_line <- rbind(df_spec_prop[,c("Latitude","Longitude")],
                         df_spec_clust[i,c("Latitude","Longitude")])
        m2 <- m2 %>%
            addPolylines(data = df_line, 
                         lat=~Latitude, 
                         lng = ~Longitude,
                         color="red")
    }
    plot2<-m2} else plot2 <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jovani SouzA @Jose m2 the object doesnt exist when you are passing it into your method chain, you are meaning to pass m1 into the method chain in order to addPolylines to create m2.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.4,-23.5), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6,-49.4,-49.2), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,]

  #Table to join df and df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, df1))

  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)

  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$Properties,
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 45, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"

  # Map for all clusters:
  m1<-leaflet(df1) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~df$Latitude, lng = ~df$Longitude, icon=icons, label=~as.character(df$cluster)) %>% 
    addPolylines(lat=~df$Latitude, lng = ~df$Longitude,color="red") %>% 
    addLegend( position = "topright", title="Cluster", colors = ai_colors[1:max(df$cluster)],labels = unique(df$cluster))

  plot1<-m1

  # Map for specific cluster and propertie
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon = 'ios-close',
      iconColor = 'black',
      library = 'ion',
      markerColor =  clust_colors)
    m2<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~Latitude, lng = ~Longitude, icon=icons, label=~cluster) 
    plot2<-m2} else plot2 <- NULL


  for(i in 1:nrow(df_spec_clust)){
    df_line <- rbind(df_spec_prop[,c("Latitude","Longitude")],
                     df_spec_clust[i,c("Latitude","Longitude")])
    m2 <- m1 %>%
      addPolylines(data = df_line, 
                   lat=~Latitude, 
                   lng = ~Longitude,
                   color="red")
  }
  plot2<-m2


  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Plot2" = plot2,
    "Data" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 5, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf1",width = "95%", height = "600")))))

                      ))),
  tabPanel("",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
               selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Map", (leafletOutput("Leaf2",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
           )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })

  output$Leaf1 <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

  output$Leaf2 <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[2]]
  })

  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 

  observeEvent(input$Filter1,{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))
  }) 


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer. But your code, the second one on the map is showing the same image as the first map, but that's not what I want. The second refers to a specific cluster. I adjusted the question and the codes for better understanding.

Comment: @JovaniSouza Is this what you are after ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648479/insert-icon-in-the-legend-of-a-map-generated-by-leaflet/61648629#61648629 see my solution there.